# How to read all replies and sent message of specific email in python

Tags: python, email, imap

I would like to read all the replies of specific email. Say for example freind1@gmail.com send "hi" to friend2@gmail.com, in turn friend2@gmail.com replies with "Hello". Then friend1@gmail.com send "How are you" which in turn friend2@gmail.com replies with "I'm good". How can I read all this 4 messages of specific email through imaplib.

Comment: This is called a 'thread' or a 'conversation'.  Some servers support the IMAP `THREAD` extension, which can help you find related messages, or specific extended searches/queries for conversation ids (like, Google IMAP Extensions).  If your server has neither of these, you may be able to search References/In-Reply-To headers for Message-IDs, or download the headers and thread them yourself.

Comment: Yes by adding the reference id in In-Reply-To-headers I can track the conversation. Thankyou